# Hebrew - Arabic grammar book

Tags: grammar, comparative-linguistics, arabic, hebrew

I've been searching for quite a long time for a Hebrew-Arabic grammar book to study both languages in more depth at the same time while being able to compare similar roots and the root system for instance. I've only been able to find old books treating general Semitic languages or enormous volumes of comparative grammars.

I was just wondering if someone could recommend me some book. It doesn't matter if it's too informal grammatically speaking or too formal, but there doesn't seem to be anything out there anyways.

Comment: I really doubt that such a book exists. It could exist and I too would be interested but I doubt somebody has made one. I would think academic Semitic stuff is all that's likely. Then again linguistics is full of surprises so you never know.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I feared so. And thank you for the text corrections, whoever that was, it's always good to see mistakes I have made writing.

Comment: Are you looking for a Hebrew grammar written in Arabic or for a book in English that covers both Hebrew and Arabic? @averroes answer is too brief for me to be sure but it looks like he's saying the former exists.

Answer (score 1):

What about these books I found on amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Languages-Comparative-Orientalia-Lovaniensia-Analecta/dp/9042908157](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9042908157)

[http://www.amazon.com/Comparative-Semitic-Linguistics-A-Manual/dp/1575060213/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1575060213)

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Semitic-Languages-Specimens-Grammatical/dp/0931464102/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0931464102)

Answer (score 0):

Of course such books exist. I bought one when I was a kid. You would find them in print in Arabic countries.

For example:

> اسم الكتاب: اللغه العبريه:قواعد و نصوص 
>   اسم المؤلف: سيد فرج راشد

Comment: I have Hebrew grammar books written in Arabic (Modern and Biblical). There are also plenty of references written in Arabic that teach Syriac and even Mandean (Aramaic languages of both Edessa and southern Iraq)

You can download them from the net but beware as you will be in breach of copy rights.